API query results descrepancy between properties
I download data from multiple properties. When I query the Google Analytics 4 API thusly,
Using an appropriately credentialed JSON key

{
property: "properties/****"
dimensions {name: "date"}
dimensions {name: "source"}
dimensions {name: "campaignName"}
metrics {name: "advertiserAdCost"}
metrics {name: "advertiserAdClicks"}
metrics {name: "advertiserAdImpressions"}
date_ranges {start_date: "2024-10-13" end_date: "2024-10-23"}
order_bys {dimension {dimension_name: "date"}
}

Several properties demonstrate the above metrics for "Shopping Free Listings" campaigns.  One property does not DESPITE;

having many multiples more traffic.

a predecessor property in GA4 which used to show these values which was deprecated for business reasons.


The change in dimension visibility seems to be strongly correlated with when the property was superseded. Additionally, I can't figure out the property level discrepancy as the above metrics aren't visible in any console dashboards.
Where/what setting am I missing, such that the "Shopping Free Listings" campaigns are visible via API query above?
I wasn't expecting to see "Shopping Free Listings" as a campaign level dimension associated with the metrics via API query:
advertiserAdCost, advertiserAdClicks, advertiserAdImpressions.
However, since I can, I would like the information to be visible across all the properties for which I download data. Or at least share the rationale for the difference with stakeholders. I guess I was expecting uniformity in query results dimension composition.
I have tried exploring the Google Analytics dashboard, Google Analytics 4 Query Explorer, linked Google Merchant Center accounts and linked Google Ads accounts. Documentation hasn't helped yet either.
My queries across properties are consistent. The programming uses the same query across all properties...
As I said, the above query shows "Shopping Free Listings" for some properties, but not others (with those websites having a history of having that campaign dimension present).
Got to be a setting I'm missing in the linkage between Google Ads, Google Merchant Center or Google Analytics 4.
any ideas?
